# Getting negative size for Pop3message

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pop3

I have requirement that i should read the mail and i should get some headers information from of mails content.

for that i am reading mails in following manner..

```
POP3Message objMsg = (POP3Message) instFolder.getMessage(totCount);   // line 1
String size = objMsg.getSize();                          // line 2
System.out.println("size :: "+size);                      // line 3 

Multipart multipartLevel_1 = (Multipart) objMsg.getContent();   // line 14 
int nmultiCount = multipartLevel_1.getCount();                  // line 15
```

at line 3 i am getting ::  size :: -1050

and at line 15 i am getting MessagingException saying..

### javax.mail.MessagingException: No inputstream from datasource

Can you tell me why i am getting negative size of message, it should return bytes count of message

and while getting multipart object why i am getting MessagingException

Thanks Advance
Rajesh V

Comment: My Big doubt is why i am getting negative count of bytes..

Comment: Have you considered that the Pop Account is sending an Error Code? And that thats part of the reason why ther is no inputstream from the Datasource.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer - google does help:

> Q: Why does the getSize method return a negative number when using
> POP3?
>
> A: Your POP3 server is broken. The POP3 provider uses the TOP
> command to fetch the headers for the message and the LIST command to
> determine the size of the entire message. It then subtracts the two
> values to determine the size of the message body. If the server
> reports the size of the entire message incorrectly, you may get a
> negative number. You can set the property "mail.pop3.disabletop" to
> "true" to disable the use of the TOP command, but note that this will
> cause any access to the message headers to fetch the entire message.

From [Oracle JavaMailAPI FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq-135477.html#pop3size)